# Change doGet() and doPost() method in service method?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

Can anyone tell me how `doGet()` and `doPost()` method change in service method?

Comment: what your question exactly?Service method calls doGet() or doPost() based on form action in request. You can override these in your servlet.

Comment: I think you may want to know the detail about the servlet, http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html

Answer (score 3):

if the client browser sends a [GET](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3) request, it will handle by [doGet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) method.
if the client browser sends a [POST](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) request, it will handle by [doPost()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) method.

Is that what you wanted to know? :O

**UPDATE:**

In side the [**service(HttpServletRequest req,
                       HttpServletResponse resp)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#service%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) method, server get the request method using [**HttpServletRequest.html#getMethod()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getMethod%28%29). Then it compare that value with available HTTP method types and call the relevant **doGet**, **doPost** or other matching method.

See **service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)** method implementation in http://www.docjar.com/html/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.java.html

Other than how the request parameters are sent to the server and the usage meant for using **GET** and **POST** methods, there is no other change AFAIK.

Comment: i know that but i what to know after request came from browser  "  how doGet and doPost change in service method "

Answer (score 1):

Because,In HttpServlet class service method is implemented and all user defined servlet class must extends Httpservlet class.It is a library class.Inside that class 2 service methods are implemented .one is public void service method ,which is basically Servlet interface method.
and another is overloaded protected void service method with 2 parameter-HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse.
public service method calls protected service method and proteced service method ,which has inside some logic.It checks which type of client request has come.if it is GET type then it will call doGet() method and if it is of type POST than it calls doPost() method.
these 2 methods are also implemented in protected service() method but we override these methods in user defined servlet class to perform our task.

Answer (score 0):

You may verify the request method type using `HttpServletRequest#getMethod()` (which this request was made).